# Вставка собственного блока (Дочерняя тема Onepress)

Tags: php, wordpress, themes, wp-theme

Делаю сайт на WordPress, использую тему OnePress. В бесплатной версии OnePress нет возможности добавлять собственные блоки. Я решил создать дочернюю тему OnePress и в functions.php вставить собственный блок. Все сделал по инструкции:
создал папку, кинул css и functions, в css прописал параметры, вставляю в functions тестовый блок, активирую дочернюю тему, но ничего не происходит - блок не появляется! И в чем, получается, проблема? Вот сам блок. Заранее большое спасибо.

```
<?php
function add_my_custom_section(){
    ?>
    <section id="my_section" class="my_section section-padding onepage-section">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="section-title-area">
                <h5 class="section-subtitle"> My section subtitle</h5>
                <h2 class="section-title"> My section title</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <!-- Your section content here, you can use bootstrap 4 elements :) -->
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Donec odio. Quisque volutpat mattis eros. Nullam malesuada erat ut turpis. Suspendisse urna nibh, viverra non, semper suscipit, posuere a, pede.</p>

            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'onepress_after_section_about', 'add_my_custom_section'  );
```